# From CupertinoTabView open a page that covers the tabs

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using `CupertinoTabScaffold` and `CupertinoTabView` for my App. For one screen that opens, I would like it to open so it entirely covers the screen, also the tabs. However, I want to use the same `Navigator` (as opposed to `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)` ) because I'm also using `RouteAware` and switching between navigators is breaking some `RouteAware` functionality. How can I do that?

Comment: Provide us with your code